# Where is the lint filter?

Tags: dryer, washing-machine, maintenance

For months now, my washer/dryer combo has become less and less effective at actually drying anything I put in it.

I've gotten the advice from some friends to check (regularly) and clean the lint filter to maintain top performance.

Supposedly all these machines have one of these but-surprise-I can't find it at all. I looked inside in the obvious spot; nothing. Checked the manual; nothing. Googled the model number; nothing.

So, ultimately, I am here. Please, tell me, anyone: Does the Lamona HJA 8703 even *have* a lint filter, and if so; how do I get to it?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: **sorry my post is for the 8702 model. I was unable to find an 8703 model 
 but would expect the manual to be v.similar.**

From what I have read, the washer dryer doesn't have a lint filter. The user manual can be found here:

https://www.northlondonappliancerepairs.co.uk/resources/lamona/27-lamona-integrated-washer-dryer-hja8702/file.html

Part 6 of the user manual suggests maintenance protocols. However part 5.5 explains how to use the cleaning cycle.

5.5 CLEAN PROGRAMME
To keep the appliance operating at peak efficiency over time, it has a CLEAN programme for regular
cleaning of the drying circuit to remove any fluff deposits.
1. After a given number of drying cycles, the CLEAN symbol lights up on the display to warn that this programme needs to be run. The warning light remains on until the CLEAN programme is carried out. The light
goes out at the end of the programme.
2. To perform the CLEAN programme, proceed as follows:
a. Make sure that the drum is completely empty and close the door.
b. Turn the knob to the CLEAN programme (see programmes table for the exact position on the knob)
c. Press the START/PAUSE button
The CLEAN programme can also be carried out even if the light on the display is not on.

6. CLEANING AND MAINTENANCE
   Important – Before carrying out any cleaning or maintenance procedure, the plug must be disconnected
   from the power supply socket.
   6.1 CLEANING THE OUTSIDE OF THE APPLIANCE
    Regular, thorough cleaning will keep your appliance looking good.
    Clean the exterior of the appliance with soap, water & a damp cloth, then dry thoroughly with a soft cloth.
    The plastic parts should just be wiped with a damp cloth.
    Do not scrape with pointed objects, or use solvents or products containing abrasive substances because
   they damage the surfaces.
    For reasons of safety, never spray the washer-dryer with jets of water.
   6.2 CLEANING THE DOOR GASKET
   Check regularly that there are no coins, buttons, nails or pins in the folds of the door gasket.
   6.3 CLEANING THE DRAIN PUMP
   The drain pump only needs cleaning if it has been blocked by buttons, coins or similar objects and the water is not
   being pumped out.
   In this case, proceed as described below.
   1.Remove the mains plug to disconnect the appliance from the electricity supply.
   2.Proceed as follows:
   use a small screwdriver as a lever to remove the
   plugs shown here, turn the plinth downwards and access the pump.

3.Extract the drain hose ”A” - (Have a small towel/cloth ready in case of spills)
Warning!
If the hose is hot, the water is hot or boiling hot. Place a shallow container on
the floor and remove the plug “B” to drain off the water.
Depending on the amount of water in the appliance, the container may have
to be emptied several times.
When no more water is coming out, close the hose again by pushing the plug
“B” firmly back into place.
 EN
21
4.Unscrew the cover of the pump “D” by turning it to the left.
Clean the pump and remove any foreign bodies.
Also check the inside “E”, making sure that the impeller turns freely; any foreign
bodies stuck in it must be removed.
5.Screw the cover back on the pump.
Secure the drain house by snapping the plug back into place "C".
Replace the plinth as follows:
Fit the bottom of the plinth first. Push it towards the cabinet and put the plugs
back into place.
6.4 CLEANING THE DETERGENT DRAWER
The detergent drawer should be kept clean, removing all solid deposits.
To simplify this operation, completely remove the detergent drawer (pull the
drawer fully out, press in the zone marked PUSH and then remove completely).
Remove the siphon "A" and clean all parts with hot water.
Fully re-insert the siphon and remove any detergent deposits before putting
the drawer back in position.
6.5 CLEANING THE WATER INTAKE FILTERS
The machine is fitted with a filter which protects the water intake valves.
The filter is in the fitting on the intake hose which is connected to the tap
The filter must be cleaned if the washer-dryer is not taking in water or the amount of water is insufficient.
To clean, proceed as follows:
 Remove the mains plug to disconnect the appliance from the electricity
supply.
 Turn off the water tap.
 Unscrew the intake hose fitting from the tap.
 Remove the intake hose fitting filter.
 Clean the filter with water, with the aid of a small brush.
 When screwing the intake hose fitting back into place, check that the filter is positioned correctly